# Sort the string when using sortable()

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a string that looks like this:

```
[TITLE|prefix=test][DYNAMIC|limit=777|random=1][STORENAME]
```

So `[TITLE]`, `[DYNAMIC]` and `[STORENAME]` are tags and I would like to sort them by using `sortable()`, which is from jQuery UI.

So for instance, if the div with the content *Dynamic* will be moved to the first place, the string should be `[DYNAMIC|limit=777|random=1][TITLE|prefix=test][STORENAME]` or if the div with the content *Title* has been moved to the last place, the string should be `[DYNAMIC|limit=777|random=1][STORENAME][TITLE|prefix=test]`

This is what I have tried so far:

```js
let tags = '[TITLE|prefix=test][DYNAMIC|limit=777|random=1][STORENAME]';

$(".sort-me").sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  cursor: "grabbing",
  opacity: 0.7,
  beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
    // Check the position of the dragged item
    $('.mt-box').each(function(key, value) {
      if (ui.item.index() === key && value.className === ui.item[0].className && $(ui.item[0]).find('.form-check-input')[0].checked) {
        const sortTags = () => {
          const querySplits = tags.split(']');
          let selectedTag = '';
          querySplits.forEach((queryValue, queryKey) => {
            if (queryValue.includes($(ui.item[0]).attr('data-mt-field').toUpperCase())) {
              selectedTag = queryValue + ']';
              querySplits[queryKey] = '';
            }
            if (querySplits[queryKey].length > 0 && querySplits[queryKey].slice(-1) !== ']') {
              querySplits[queryKey] += ']';
            }
          });
          querySplits.splice(ui.item.index(), 0, selectedTag);
          tags = querySplits.filter((el) => el).join(']').replace(/[\]]]+/, ']');
          console.log(tags);
        }

        sortTags();

      }
    });
  }
});
```

If you set any item in the first place, the sorting works correctly. But if you move anything else, for instance, the first item in second or in third place, the sorting will not be correct.

Please see my code on [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4pyqfhx9/) and see the console when moving the items.

Comment: Why not attach the "tags" to the divs up-front, then just read them back when you've dragged?   as *an example* `$('[data-mt-field="storename"]').data(querySplits[2])`

Comment: @freedomn-m what is the difference between storing the string in data attributes and variables? The string should be the same.

Comment: My suggestion is to split the string up at the start - into the 3 separate divs.  Then, when it's time to read it back in order, it's a simple `$(".mt-box").map((i,e)=>return $(this).data("split"))`.  The difference is that the order is already provided by the DOM so you don't need to "re-sort" the strings based on the order of the DOM elements.

Comment: @freedomn-m I get your point but this is exactly why I'm using `$('.mt-box').each(function(key, value) {`, since all elements with the class `mt-box` should be already sorted by DOM.

Comment: Right, you're getting the sorted DOM nodes, then attempting to resort the string based on that - when there's no need if the strings come from the DOM nodes

Comment: It's only a suggestion - if you're set on splitting and sorting in one go, then carry on

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between the tags and the HTML. I don't see how you could build one from the other or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that within the loop I've been setting the value to an empty string. Then when using `splice()`, the value may get placed in the correct position but the result does not look correct, since the array contains values that are empty. So in that case I have used `querySplits.filter((v) => v != '');` to remove all elements from the array which are empty.

Another wrong thing was that I've been using `ui.item.index()` as the first parameter of `splice()` but it should be `key`.

See the full code:

```js
let tags = '[TITLE|prefix=test][DYNAMIC|limit=777|random=1][STORENAME]';

$(".sort-me").sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
  cursor: "grabbing",
  opacity: 0.7,
  beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
    // Check the position of the dragged item
    $('.mt-box').each(function(key, value) {    
      if (value.className === ui.item[0].className && $(ui.item[0]).find('.form-check-input')[0].checked) {
        const sortTags = () => {
          let querySplits = tags.split(']');
          let selectedTag = '';
          querySplits.forEach((queryValue, queryKey) => {
            // Check if the query includes the tag
            if (queryValue.includes($(ui.item[0]).attr('data-mt-field').toUpperCase())) {
                // If match. store the value in a variable and prepend ], since we have used split(']')
              selectedTag = queryValue + ']';
              // Delte the value of that tag from the array
              querySplits[queryKey] = '';
            }
            // Add ], if it's missing in a valid value
            if (querySplits[queryKey].length > 0 && querySplits[queryKey].slice(-1) !== ']') {
              querySplits[queryKey] += ']';
            }
          });
          querySplits = querySplits.filter((v) => v != '');
          querySplits.splice(key, 0, selectedTag);
          tags = querySplits.filter((el) => el).join(']').replace(/[\]]]+/, ']');
          console.log(tags);          
        }

        sortTags();

      }
    });
  }
});
```